# debugview equivalent in linux

Tags: linux

Is there a Linux equivalent of Windows `DebugView`? I want to monitor a Linux C/C++ program's `print` statements on console remotely. I am interested in monitoring user-space programs (I tried to use `dmesg` but it works only for kernel messages AFAIK)

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Do you really only want to look at the output to stdout?

Comment: Interesting that almost every Linux programmer starts the answer to such question with "I don't know what is DebugView, but you can try ...". I am sure they know!

Comment: Alex: I'm sure they know what OutputDebugStringW/A is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `syslog` facility (`man syslog`) - It's the standard Unix/Linux framework for logging output. Most modern implementations (`syslog-ng`, `rsyslog`) allow very advanced configurations, including distribution of logging messages over networks, etc.

update:

If you just want to capture the output of a bunch of programs, while allowing them to print to the console as usual, then you can use 'tee'. For example

```
prog1 | tee outputs &     # start prog1 and copy stdout to the file "outputs" as well
prog2 | tee -a outputs &  # start prog2 and append stdout to the file "outputs"
```

Then, from another place, you can observe how the `outputs` is filled using `tail`. i.e.

```
tail -f outputs
```

or

```
tail -f outputs | nc -l 9999
```

If you want to read the output over network (just telnet to the machine on port 9999)

Comment: It have looked at syslog-ng. It would do ok.. but I have a huge set of distributed programs which use g_prints. how can i get them to show up in 1 place using syslog-ng?

Comment: g_printf is *not* meant to be used for debugging output. This is even mentioned in the glib docs. glib has g_log for this purpose (which can be directed to output to syslog or anything you want). If you have g_printf and cannot do anything about it, then you'll need to redirect their output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to fit, but maybe [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) could work. [Strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) will print every system call a program passed as parameter make.